# How to pad an input with a certain number(not with zeros)?

Tags: angular9

I want to set a maximum value for a number.

How to pad an input number with a certain number especially the number 9?

For example, if my input is 5, output would be 99999. If my input is 8, the output would be 99999999.

Comment: Try doing this with [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and add debugging details.

Answer (score 0):

In template File:

```
<input type="number" (keyup)="addNumber($event)" [(ngModel)]="numValue">
```

tsFile:

```
ddNumber(event) {
if (event.target.value == 9) {
  this.numValue = 9999999;
} else if (event.target.value == 8) {
  this.numValue = 9999999999;
}
```

}

this is simple approach...u can write the hostlistener event,we can based on the input value.

Comment: Not the best approach since I want the input not to be just 9 and 8, but limitless. And coding it manually doesn't looks good on paper.